# Sort csv by numerical values

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I was looking and reading previous questions and answers similar to mine, but  didn't find a good solution to my case.

I have a csv file with 2 columns. One is numerical values (100, 40, 350 etc.), and the other is a list of pictures tag name (i.e. computer.jpg).

What I am trying to do is to sort the file by the first column (i.e. the values) in ascending manner. That also means that I want the pair of the value (the image name) to move accordingly with it.

This is what I have so far:

```css
import csv
import operator
sample=open('random.csv', "r")
csv1=csv.reader(sample, delimiter='.')
header=next(csv1, None)
sort= sorted(csv1, key=operator.itemgetter(0))

with open('randomized.csv', "wb") as f:
    csv_writer=csv.writer(f, delimiter='.')
    if header:
        csv_writer.writerow(header)
    csv_writer.writerows(sort)
```

The resulted sorted list, however, is like this: 100, 175, 20, 250, 3.

I tried some other codes, like this:

```css
sort=csv1.sort(key=lambda row: row[0], reverse=True)
```

But I receive an error back: AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'sort'

I read about one option which is to convert the numbers to strings before sorting, and then converting them back to numbers before writing the file, but don't really have the tools to do it.

Anyone has a clue how to get this one down?

Comment: Can you provide example of the file, or its dummy version.

Comment: Couldn't upload and edit my post (don't have enough reputation). But here's a link: http://s12.postimg.org/zfbjsa6ul/Screenshot_2015_03_28_at_17_11_05.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to cast to int:

```
srt= sorted(csv1, key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
```

You are sorting strings where `100 < 12`

`sort=csv1.sort(key=lambda row: row[0], reverse=True)` gives you an error because `csv1` is a reader object not a list, you would have to call `list` on the `reader` object but you may as well just use sorted.

You can see using ints gives very different output:

```
In [46]: l = ["100","2","12","200"]

In [47]: sorted(l)
Out[47]: ['100', '12', '2', '200']

In [48]: sorted(l,key=lambda x: int(x))
Out[48]: ['2', '12', '100', '200']
```

Sorting as strings python goes char by char, the first char with a greater value will be considered a higher value so as in the first sorted output 100 is considered < 12 because 2 > 0.

Putting it all together:

```
import csv

with open('random.csv') as sample, open('randomized.csv', "w") as out:
    csv1=csv.reader(sample)
    header = next(csv1, None)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(out)
    if header:
        csv_writer.writerow(header)
    csv_writer.writerows(sorted(csv1, key=lambda x:int(x[0])))
```

The output will be:

```
value, image
50, bottle.jpg
75, broomstick.jpg
175, book.jpg
100, car.jpg
```

Which is not putting the data into one column, the `,` is what delimits each column, i.e comma seperated values.

Comment: Thanks, Padraic. I've tried to run it but got this: "ValueError: invalid literal for int(): with base 10: 50,'book' - I should mention that 50 is one of my values, and book is one of the images.
Should I put them back to numbers before writing the csv?

Comment: are you sure  `,` is the not actual delimiter? Try `csv1=csv.reader(sample)`

Comment: Great, the sorting works perfectly now! However, the new file has both the value and the image in one column, joint by a comma. Also, the image name (right after the comma) is like this: "image.jpg." (that is, with added "_"). So from being in two different columns, I have this in one column 50."bottle.jpg"

Comment: Wait, you want the rest of the file? It something like this: http://s12.postimg.org/zfbjsa6ul/Screenshot_2015_03_28_at_17_11_05.png

Comment: @HBS, that is not in one column, the `,` delimits the columns

Comment: The problem is that these images serve as a link to stored images on my computer, and the could should run (and present them). Is there a way that I can bring it back to normal - having two separate columns, and without the "" ?

Comment: they are two separate columns, the output I added is exactly the output you will get